# Custom uninstall Action c#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, uninstallation

I have some condition, which I have to check at the time of uninstall, if conditions match then I want to stop the installation process and want to roll back the uninstall process.

Currently I am using the custom actions for the uninstalling using installer class. In which I check for condition whether match or not? if match then I have done rollback and no then the uninstallation will continue.

I have used following code in uninstall script action.

```
public override void Uninstall(IDictionary savedState)
        {
            if (Condition)
            {
                Rollback(savedState);
            }
            else
            {
                base.Uninstall(savedState);
            }

        }
```

But this code is not able to rollback the uninstall process. Let me know what is wrong with this code. if any new idea then let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Throw an `InstallException` and it will rollback. Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installexception.aspx).

```
public override void Uninstall(IDictionary savedState)
{
    if (Condition)
    {
        throw new InstallException("blah blah");
        // What ever you want to do after
    }
    else
    {
        base.Uninstall(savedState);
    }               
}
```

Your code won't work. Why?

When rollback happens Rollback custom action is called.

Its not other way round that calling Rollback custom action will cause Rollback.

Comment: thx for replay.I have try to throw an exception but now problem is, it 's showing an exception error window. is there any way to hide that window.

Comment: Unfortunately No. That window tells user why rollback is called. In my code it will show "blah blah"

Comment: Addtionally it shows "Error 1001 .................". There seems to be a way out in Wix/Installshield, but not in Visual studio deployment projects.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal, But In my project, I need to do it in Visual Studio Deployment project. So I am exploring further [1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368554(v=vs.85).aspx), [2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368609(v=vs.85).aspx)